# OpenVPN: quit on proxy connection error

Tags: proxy, openvpn

My goal is to try various proxy ports. My application would call openvpn at first with one set of proxy settings. If it fails, then it takes the other set. For now my application tries another set only, if openvpn process exits.

If I set --connect-retry-max to 1, I can see DISCONNECTED state through the management interface. But I'll get the same state, when the established network connection would fail during the session.

Is there any option to make openvpn quit on proxy connection error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am confused here, why do you want your VPN to quit? Why not just generate an OpenVPN configuration file with multiple connection profiles, and let OpenVPN cycle between them on its own?

The xample from the OpenVPN man page seems to illustrate this.

```
      <connection>
      remote 198.19.34.56 1194 udp
      </connection>

      <connection>
      remote 198.19.34.56 443 tcp
      </connection>

      <connection>
      remote 198.19.34.56 443 tcp
      http-proxy 192.168.0.8 8080
      </connection>

      <connection>
      remote 198.19.36.99 443 tcp
      http-proxy 192.168.0.8 3128
      </connection>
```